# Regex in Bash "if" Statement

Tags: regex, bash

```
if [[ $1  =~ ^\'*\"*[\d+\w+]+\'*\"*$ ]]
    then
        echo true
    else
        echo error
        exit 1
fi
```

This regex seems to be correct (verified with https://regexr.com, and other regex sites), however, the script will evaluate to false.
Any idea why?

For this argument, I am expecting a line such as:

Will0w

To be matched, however, no luck.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: *"verified with https://regexr.com, and other regex sites"*: here is your error, bash regexes don't use the same syntax (and don't have the same behaviour) than javascript or php patterns. Search about the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax.

Comment: Specifically, `\d` and `\w` are not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if [[ $1  =~ ^\'*\"*[[:alnum:]]+\'*\"*$ ]]
    then
        echo true
    else
        echo error
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `[a-Z]` depends on `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` being adjacent in the current locale. Use the POSIX character class `[[:alnum:]]` instead, which also includes `0-9`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using grep:

```
if echo $1 | grep -qP "^\'*\"*[\d+\w+]+\'*\"*$"
    then
        echo true
    else
        echo error
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `grep -qP "^\'*\"*[\d+\w+]+\'*\"*$" <<< "$1"` will be more efficient as it eliminates the fork needed for the pipe.